# Objective C error "Expected identifier or '(' "

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, compiler-errors

I'm using `UITableView` to try and display some info in my app so naturally I want to use the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods to help set that up but I'm getting the following error `Expected Identifier or '('`. This is my code:

```
@interface ListVC (): UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> //error location

@end

@implementation ListVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ài", @"bā", @"ba", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong. If you are intended to put an extension in your implementation file (.m) then this is the right syntax:

```
@interface ListVC ()

@end
```

If you want to keep your protocols conformation in header then and the correct syntax is:

```
@interface ListVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

And if you want to keep your protocols conformation in implementation file (which is probably the case for you) then and the correct syntax is:

```
@interface ListVC () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

Comment: This is only half right. The protocols in this case should be on the class extension and not in the public header file. There is no reason to publicly declare that the view controller conforms to these protocols.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. Corrected my post!

Answer (score 1):

When declaring class extension, you should not add the superclass. Superclass is already present in the class declaration and you cannot change it in class extension.

```
@interface ListVC () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: FYI - It's a class extension, not a class continuation.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. Didn't know the official term was class extension. Probably picked it up in an old document and never realized it's not an official name.